# How to setup system of InfluxDB on Docker instance on Win10 to Connect to database from Windows system?

Tags: docker, influxdb, influxdb-python

I would like to create a docker container hosting an InfluxDB as test environment for a Python project of mine. My PC is running under Win10, but Docker needs to provide a Linux-environment for the InfluxDB. I managed to install docker and influxDB (docker pull influxdb) and to create a database therein, so this part works fine. Docker's network configuration says it is on subnet address 10.0.75.0, subnet mask 255.255.255.0, which seems to fit to my DockerNAT when I do an `ipconfig`.

Now I want to connect to this Docker/InfluxDB "server" from my Windows10 environment (where PyCharm is running). I found this code snippet to connect to the DB via Python:

```
_influxClient = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port='8086')
```

but this yields a `_influxClient = None`

I have no idea how to proceed as I didn't find appropriate hints in the web. Or maybe I am using the whole Docker/InfluxDB etup wrongly? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this: [I want to connect to a container from Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)? Did you publish any port at the `docker run ...` command?

Comment: Show your docker-compose file

Comment: @tgogos: I am using the following command to run docker: docker run --name=influxdb -d -p 8086:8086 influxdb`

Comment: @Ntwobike: ?? I don't know how to do that...

Comment: ok, i thought you have multiple containers. Then first download and install the cli(https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads/).
Then try to login to the contianer influxdb. You are already mapping to the 8086 port. So if you type influx then you should be able to login to the container db instance(more: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/shell/).

Comment: @Ntwobike: this works fine for me. In the Docker container I can logon and everything. Still, I cannot connect via Python code running on my Win-PC - so from "outside" of the Docker container

Comment: may be this helps https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/blob/master/examples/tutorial.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I was running docker / influxDb with a local admin account, while I ran python as a normal user. As soon as I switched to running docker as normal user it worked.